# Where to install NSS modules on CoreOS?

Tags: coreos, nss

I have a custom NSS module that I wrote and I typically install it by copying the library like so...

```
cp libnss_mymodule.so.0 /lib64/
```

... then I add my module to the **/etc/nsswitch.conf** ...

```
$ grep mymodule /etc/nsswitch.conf
passwd: mymodule files usrfiles sss systemd
group: mymodule files usrfiles sss systemd
```

This works for me in CentOS 7, but it doesn't work in CoreOS because **/lib64** is on a read-only filesystem.  Where can I put the shared object library on CoreOS that will be visible to nsdispath() ?

EDIT:  I tried adding the file to **/opt/me/lib64** and putting that in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.  It didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by putting the libraries **/opt/mything/lib64** and then modifying the following system configurations:

Added the following line to **/etc/environment**:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/mything/lib64
```

Added the following line to **/etc/systemd/system.conf**:

```
DefaultEnvironment=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/mything/lib64
```

Then ran the following command:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

This made it possible for NSS to find the custom NSS modules I built.

Answer (score 0):

[Build a new image containing your changes with the developer SDK.](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/sdk-modifying-coreos.html)

CoreOS calls itself immutable; this is by design.

Comment: I know this.  I still need my NSS module to work.

Comment: @Ishpeck OK, so go on and do it.